# PHP curl option to set defaultProxy like .Net

Tags: php

Do we have any option to set defaultProxy(Available in .Net) kind of setting in PHP curl.

I am trying to access a website through CURL in my development environment which is hosted in our office environment.

Through PHP CURL it's not accessible but when we try to access the same website through  .Net with defaultProxy enabled true, then it's working fine there.

I have tried many option but not able to resolve this issue as of now.

I really wants to access that website through my PHP curl script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code

```
        $url = 'http://yourdomain.com';
        $proxy = '127.0.0.1:port_no';
        //$proxyauth = 'user:password'; // in case if it has authentication
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth); // uncomment 
        if no auth
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        print_r($response) ;
```

Comment: How to get the port number?

Comment: hit the `netstat -a` commond  on cmd